# iOS: hide/disable new iOS bottom bar

Tags: ios, ipad, hide, appcelerator

There is anyway to hide or disable the new iOS 9 bottom bar on iPad?

[image: iOS bottom bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDyyB.png)

Comment: Are you seeing this on simulator or device ?

Comment: Yes, still haven't tried this on a real device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following property on TextFields and TextAreas to hide this new actions bar:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-property-showUndoRedoActions

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this new property

Answer (score -1):

Isn't that just the keyboard toolbar?  I'm guessing you're running it on the iOS simulator which often errors and doesn't show the keyboard but will still show the toolbar.  If you hide the keyboard (blur all text input capable UI elements) the toolbar hides as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try this on a real iPad device.

Every time that this bar appears, all the visible UI ScrollableViews can't scroll by user touch, it's a little bit annoying

Answer (score -1):

According to the iOS guide the toolbar "Can hide when the keyboard appears, the user makes a gesture, or when the containing view controller transitions to a vertically compact environment." So, A real device test would demonstrate the behavior. Reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW4